# Type Error while using interval and map with RXJS in Typescript. errorcode: ts(2740)

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-typings, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to use rxjs in typescript for one of my projects and am struggling with typing one function.
The function I am trying to give a type (Return value type) is **createMessageSource**.

```
import { interval, Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

type MessageType = {
      name: string;
      content: string;
}

const createMessageSource =
      (period: number, name: string, content: string) =>
        interval(period)
          .pipe(map(i => ({
            name,
            content: `${content} - ${i}`,
          })));
```

As far as I understand the problem, the return value of the pipe command should be an Observable or a Subscription. So I tried the following types so far:

```
const createMessageSource: Observable<MessageType[]> = ...

const createMessageSource: Subscription = ...
```

Both combinations end in the following typescript error shown in vscode:

*Type '(period: number, name: string, attribute: string) => Observable<{ name: string; content: number; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<MessageType[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)*

Thx for the help beforehand

Comment: Correct type for `createMessageSource`  is `Observable<MessageType>` because your code doesn't emit arrays but single objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that `.pipe()` returns an Observable. Your problem is that `createMessageSource` is not an Observable, but a **Function that returns an Observable** :-)

So you could define a new `MessageFactory` type:

```
type MessageSourceFactory = (period: number, name: string, content: string) => Observable<MessageType>;


const createMessageSource: MessageSourceFactory =
      (period: number, name: string, content: string) =>
        interval(period).pipe(
          map(i => ({
            name,
            content: `${content} - ${i}`,
          }))
        );
```

or you could define it like a function, if that suits your needs:

```
function createMessageSource(period: number, name: string, content: string): Observable<MessageType> {
  return interval(period).pipe(
    map(i => ({
      name,
      content: `${content} - ${i}`,
    }))
  );
}
```

Comment: what a chad. Thx for the quick help boss. Worked fine and I feel dumb like I should!
God bless you

Comment: Happy to help. We all have those moments :-)